# Is there a way to get passed arguments from already started webdriver (Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm wondering if there is a way to find the parameters that are passed to the selenium web driver if you don't have the source code of the app itself, but the browser is visible and you can interact with it.

By arguments, I mean all the settings that are different from the default ones that the web driver is started with default. For an example user agent, --commands, etc ...

Comment: Try casting the `IWebDriver` object to a specific web driver. Then inspect the methods and properties that are available.

Comment: The short answer is yes, but you would have to spend the time to collect and interrogate the application.   By default `selenium` doesn't pass arguments to web driver.  The app developer is the one that codes in the arguments.  Additionally, the web drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge can have similar arguments, but some are unique to the driver being called.

Comment: Some options for Chrome can be viewed by entering "chrome://version/" in the browser's location bar and hitting enter.

Comment: @pcalkins that's it, I've just checked and there is everything I need.
Please post this as the answer so I can assign you the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options for Chrome can be viewed by entering "chrome://version/" in the browser's location bar and hitting enter.